# collating multiple rows of a column in a panda to one row while maintaining the data type of the column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a panda with a few columns like this

```
username A time place
AAA      B 1    YYY
AAA      C 2    YYY
AAA      D 1    YYY
AAA      B 3    ZZZ
AAA      C 4    ZZZ
AAA      B 3    ZZZ
BBB      B 1    YYY
BBB      C 2    YYY
BBB      D 1    YYY
BBB      B 7    ZZZ
BBB      C 8    ZZZ
BBB      B 9    ZZZ
CCC      B 6    YYY
CCC      C 5    YYY
CCC      D 8    YYY
CCC      B 7    ZZZ
CCC      C 8    ZZZ
CCC      B 9    ZZZ
```

in the above panda, all the columns except time are strings. TIme is a float column.

I am trying create a sequence such that for every username, I want the all the rows of a username collated to one row. The output dataframe wants to look like this.

```
username A           time        place
AAA      B+C+D+B+C+B 1+2+1+3+4+3 YYY+YYY+YYY+ZZZ+ZZZ+ZZZ
BBB      B+C+D+B+C+B 1+2+1+7+8+9 YYY+YYY+YYY+ZZZ+ZZZ+ZZZ
CCC      B+C+D+B+C+B 6+5+8+7+8+9 YYY+YYY+YYY+ZZZ+ZZZ+ZZZ
```

I am using the '+' as a separator, but it can be any character generally used for separators(like ,/ \ ..etc)

I have been able to do that for all the columns using

```
df.groupby('username')['A].apply('+',join).reset_index()
```

and the same for all columns. I am finally merging all the individual df`s to get the form I want.

For the time column I am able to do but am looking to get a column of type floats. I am having difficulty doing that. Hoping somebody more knowledgeable can guide me here.

I have even tried changing the output column after the fact with 
    df['time'].astype(float)

but am getting all NaN`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need convert all columns to strings with [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
df = df.astype(str).groupby('username', as_index=False).agg('+'.join)
print (df)
  username            A                     time                    place
0      AAA  B+C+D+B+C+B  1.0+2.0+1.0+3.0+4.0+3.0  YYY+YYY+YYY+ZZZ+ZZZ+ZZZ
1      BBB  B+C+D+B+C+B  1.0+2.0+1.0+7.0+8.0+9.0  YYY+YYY+YYY+ZZZ+ZZZ+ZZZ
2      CCC  B+C+D+B+C+B  6.0+5.0+8.0+7.0+8.0+9.0  YYY+YYY+YYY+ZZZ+ZZZ+ZZZ
```

If need `sum` numeric columns and join by `+` strings columns:

```
df = (df.groupby('username', as_index=False)
       .agg(lambda x: x.sum() if np.issubdtype(x.dtype, np.number) else '+'.join(x)))
print (df)
  username            A  time                    place
0      AAA  B+C+D+B+C+B  14.0  YYY+YYY+YYY+ZZZ+ZZZ+ZZZ
1      BBB  B+C+D+B+C+B  28.0  YYY+YYY+YYY+ZZZ+ZZZ+ZZZ
2      CCC  B+C+D+B+C+B  43.0  YYY+YYY+YYY+ZZZ+ZZZ+ZZZ
```

Comment: I am trying to get the time column to be a float in the final output. If that is not possible, I dont mind getting tips on how to make the time column a float after the agg. thx

Comment: So for `AAA` need `14.0` for time?

Comment: Cannot vote due to lack of reputation points. My Q is answered.